# pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() with DROP TABLE command

Tags: postgresql, triggers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ddl_command_test()
RETURNS event_trigger
AS $$
DECLARE
    obj record;
BEGIN
    FOR obj IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()
        LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE '% commnad on oid: %',
                 tg_tag,
                 obj.objid;

            RAISE NOTICE 'triggered';
        END LOOP;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE EVENT TRIGGER test_ddl ON ddl_command_end
   EXECUTE FUNCTION ddl_command_test();
```

While `pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()` function returns info for table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(
    col int
);
```

It not prints notification message when table is dropped:

```
DROP TABLE test_table;
```

Don't get why, because [event-trigger-matrix](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-trigger-matrix.html) shows that `ddl_​command_​end` includes `DROP TABLE` command also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the documentation [event-trigger-matrix](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-trigger-matrix.html) says that `ddl_command_end` can be used for `DROP` statements, I also struggled with that issue in the past.

Thereby, I found this workaround, which involves creating a specific function that fetches `FROM pg_event_trigger_dropped_objects()`, to notify when the `DROP` statement is used.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ddl_drop_command_test()
RETURNS event_trigger
AS $$
DECLARE
    obj record;
BEGIN
    FOR obj IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_dropped_objects()
        LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE '% commnad on oid: %',
                 tg_tag,
                 obj.objid;

            RAISE NOTICE 'triggered';
        END LOOP;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Further, you need to use `ON sql_drop` to create your event trigger. The `WHEN TAG` can be incremented with `DROP SCHEMA` and other Postgres objects.

```
CREATE EVENT TRIGGER drop_test ON sql_drop 
WHEN TAG IN ('DROP TABLE')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE ddl_drop_command_test();
```

Comment: but if I need drop table and drop function  how to specify it in the trigger `WHEN TAG IN ('DROP TABLE')`

Comment: @Andrey www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/event-trigger-matrix.html